# Хочу сделать, чтобы бот рассчитывал индекс массы тела по формуле

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Хочу сделать, чтобы бот рассчитывал индекс массы тела по формуле. Для этого нужно, чтобы человек ввел свой вес (пусть будет 70) и рост (пусть будет 1.8), после чего подставляется в формулу `70:(1.8 * 1.8)` и значение отправляется пользователю. Заранее спасибо за помощь

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Начать заниматься']])
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Измерить индекс массы тела']])
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Наша группа спорта️‍']])
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Наши проекты']])
    keyboard.add(*[types.KeyboardButton(name) for name in ['Пожелания']])
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите действие', reply_markup=keyboard)

    elif message.text == 'Измерить индекс массы тела':
        indextela = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В скором времени появится', reply_markup=indextela)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ves = 70
rost = 1.8

index=ves/(rost**2)
```

Comment: А как чтобы человек сам ввел числа и они подставились в формулу?

Comment: Ну так делайте обработчик при нажатии допустим на кнопку в боте, чтобы отправлял сообщение и просил ввести вес и рост через запятую. Полученные параметры подставляйте в формулу.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо